# In TSQL, why does an UPDATE using += on a column not add subsequent values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When creating an UPDATE statement, I thought using += would add columns on either side and save it to the column on the left. This seems to work with a SELECT statement and a variable but not with columns in an UPDATE statement.

It appears that the update statement is only choosing the lowest value from the CROSS JOIN and performing that operation but it seems to neglect the remaining rows containing values (2,3,4). I would have thought the last SELECT would have returned @Val = 10, Val = 10

Why does it not add the values (2,3,4) into the column for the UPDATE statement?

```
SELECT 0 AS Val INTO #MyTable

DECLARE @Val AS INT = 0

UPDATE MyTable
SET MyTable.Val += TableValues.AddVal
FROM #MyTable MyTable
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT       1 AS AddVal 
        UNION SELECT 2 AS AddVal
        UNION SELECT 3 AS AddVal
        UNION SELECT 4 AS AddVal
    ) TableValues

SELECT @Val += TableValues.AddVal
FROM #MyTable MyTable
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT       1 AS AddVal 
        UNION SELECT 2 AS AddVal
        UNION SELECT 3 AS AddVal
        UNION SELECT 4 AS AddVal
    ) TableValues

SELECT @Val AS [@Val], * FROM #MyTable

DROP TABLE #MyTable
```

Comment: The update is not a loop - you've told it to update the value from the select but not told it which of the values you want to use - so it works by adding the first value that comes back from the select -> 0+1 = 1. It sounds like you want `SUM` :)

Comment: @Bridge,  I figured the SELECT and the UPDATE would work in a similar fashion. I see `@Val` in the SELECT to be the approximate equivalant of MYTable.Val in the UPDATE.  SUMing the values works for what the query, however, I don't understand why there is a difference in behavior with the UPDATE and SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `SUM` to add the all values and then add it to required column in the other table.

```
update MyTable
set MyTable.Val = MyTable.Val + TableValues.AddVal
from #MyTable MyTable
cross join (
    select sum(AddVal) as AddVal
    from (
        select 1 as AddVal
        union
        select 2 as AddVal
        union
        select 3 as AddVal
        union
        select 4 as AddVal
        ) t
    ) TableValues
```

Which in your case is effectively:

```
update #MyTable
set Val = Val + 10
```

Comment: I know SUM would work but I'm trying to understand the difference to why using a SELECT with variable will output what I'm expected but not with the UPDATE.

Comment: The reason is as @Bridge mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: @GurV It would seem not, He's not really asking how to solve the problem He's looking to understand Why SQL does it different between the Select and Update; It's unexpected that they are working differently.